# filter dataframe of frozensets if they have a certain elemnet

Tags: python, pandas, frozenset

I would like to filter a datframe that has association rules results. I want antecedents that contain an element like H or L in my case. The antecedents are frozenset types. I tried Hrules but it is not working.

```
Hrules=fdem_rules['H'  in fdem_rules['antecedents']]
Hrules=fdem_rules[frozenset({'H'})  in fdem_rules['antecedents']]
```

did not work

In the following example, I need only rows 46 and 89  as they have H.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'antecedents': [frozenset({'N', 'M', '60'}), frozenset({'H', 'AorE'}), frozenset({'0-35', 'H', 'AorE', '60'}), frozenset({'AorE', 'M', '60', '0'}), frozenset({'0-35', 'F'})]})
```

```
             antecedents
75            (N, M, 60)
46             (H, AorE)
89   (0-35, H, AorE, 60)
103     (AorE, M, 60, 0)
38             (0-35, F)
```

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I provided 2 examples of antecedents frozensets, I want to filter out those rows where H does not appear in the antecedents. Pleaes let me know what you mean by reproducible example?

Comment: Well, if I were to copy your code, this wouldn't give me a dataframe but an error. I don't know what "fdem_rules is dataframe results of a apriori algo" is. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) means that I can reproduce your data: copy code -> paste -> get working object.

Comment: thank you, I edited it. I hope it is ok now.

Comment: I further simplified your question to only keep the minimal relevant data ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### set/frozenset methods

You can use `apply` with set/frozenset's method. Here to check is at least H or L is present, one can use the negation of `{'H', 'L'}.isdisjoint`:

```
match = {'H', 'L'}
df['H or L'] = ~df['antecedents'].apply(match.isdisjoint)
```

A much faster variant of the above is to use a list comprehension:

```
match = {'H', 'L'}
df['H or L'] = [not match.isdisjoint(x) for x in df['antecedents']]
```

###### explode+isin+aggregate

Another option is to `explode` the frozenset, use `isin`, and aggregate the result with `groupby`+`any`:

```
match = {'H', 'L'}
df['H or L'] = df['antecedents'].explode().isin(match).groupby(level=0).any()
```

output:

```
>>> df[['antecedents', 'H or L']]
             antecedents  H or L
75            (N, M, 60)   False
46             (H, AorE)    True
89   (0-35, H, AorE, 60)    True
103     (AorE, M, 60, 0)   False
38             (0-35, F)   False
```

###### slicing matching rows

```
match = {'H', 'L'}
idx = [not match.isdisjoint(x) for x in df['antecedents']]
df[idx]
```

output:

```
            antecedents consequents other_cols
46            (H, AorE)         (N)        ...
89  (0-35, H, AorE, 60)         (0)        ...
```